# All maximal subgroups are Sylow subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory, nilpotent-groups, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be a group in which all maximal non-trivial subgroups are Sylow subgroups. Then $G$ isn't a simple non-abelian group.

I know how to prove this by relying on the theorem that if all maximal subgroups are nilpotent, then the group itself is solvable (in particular, isn't simple non-abelian group).

But I wonder if it's possible to prove this statement in another way?

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Must *Then $G$ isn't simple Abelian*, be *Then $G$ is not simple*? I mean, suppose $G$ is simple abelian, then it is cyclic of prime order and $\{1\}$ would be the maximal subgroup..

Comment: This is written very oddly. Do you mean that if $G$ is a group such that all maximal non-trivial subgroups are Sylow subgroups, then $G$ is not a simple group?

Comment: I apologize. I will correct the statement now.

Comment: A cyclic group of prime order satisfies the condition that "all maximal non-trivial subgroups are Sylow subgroups" by vacuity, since it has no maximal non-trivial subgroup.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I agree with your statement, but it doesn't contradict my statement, since I claim that under such conditions the group $G$ isn't a simple non-abelian group. However, a cyclic group of prime order is simple, but abelian. Perhaps there was a such contradiction before my corrections of this statement. Therefore, once again I apologize for my inattention.

Comment: You could prove that all pairs of  Sylow $p$-subgroups have trivial intersection for all primes $p$ and then do a counting argument.

Comment: I know about this proof. This is exactly how the theorem I wrote about in my question is proved.

I just thought there was a simpler proof of the fact I was writing about. After all, here the maximal subgroups are the Sylow subgroups. And, perhaps, with this in mind, other considerations could be used.

Comment: Such groups have the unusual property that all of their proper subgroups have prime power order, but it is not clear how to use that. The proof I suggested uses only Sylow's Theorem. and the fact that proper subgroups of $p$-groups are properly contained in their normalizers.

Comment: We can then conclude that all elements in this group have a prime order and then we can use the classification of simple groups, and conclude that only $A_5$ is the only simple non-Abelian subgroup that has all elements of a simple order. But even it doesn't satisfy our condition. But to prove this, it takes much more effort than applying the theorem I proposed. But in general, it's okay. I was just curious (nothing more) to find out if there is an opportunity to prove this statement easier than the theorem that I proposed.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation of the computations that Derek Holt had in mind.

Let
$$
|G|=n=p_1^{s_1}\ldots p_r^{s_r},
$$
where $p_i$ are distinct prime numbers
and let $P_i$ be a Sylow $p_i$-subgroup.
We assume that $N_G(P_i)=P_i$ for all $i$ and $r\geq2$.

Since any pair of Sylow $p_i$-subgroups has a trivial intersection and the number of Sylow $p_i$-subgroups is
$$
|G:N_G(P_i)|=|G:P_i|=\frac{n}{p_i^{s_i}},
$$
it follows that the number of $p_i$-elements in $G$ is
$$
(p_i^{s_i}-1)\frac{n}{p_i^{s_i}}.
$$
Hence
$$
n\geq1+\sum_i(p_i^{s_i}-1)\frac{n}{p_i^{s_i}}=1+rn-n\left(\frac{1}{p_1^{s_1}}+\ldots+\frac{1}{p_r^{s_r}}\right)\geq1+rn-n\cdot\frac{r}{2}=1+n\cdot\frac{r}{2}\geq n+1.
$$
Contradiction.

Comment: @NickyHekster If $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup then it is contained in a maximal subgroup (or is the whole group!), and this maximal subgroup is a Sylow.

Comment: By the way, once you know that such groups are solvable, I think you can even classify them. I think they are either cyclic of order $pq$ ($p \neq q$ primes), or semidirect products of the form $C_p^d \rtimes C_q$, where $C_q$ acts irreducibly on $C_p^d$.

Comment: @spin Yes, it seems to be true.